# How can I avoid having NSFileWrapper use lots memory when writing the file

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, nsfilemanager, nsfilewrapper

I have an app that is using `NSFileWrapper` to create a backup of the user's data. This backup file contains text and media files (compression is not relevant here). Sometimes these backup files get quite large, over 200 MB in size. When I call `NSFileWrapper -writeToURL...` it appears to load the entire contents into memory as part of the writing process. On older devices, this causes my app to be terminated by the system due to memory constraints.

Is there a simple way to avoid having `NSFileWrapper` load everything into memory? I've read through every `NSFileWrapper` question on here that I could find. Any suggestions on how to tackle this?

Here is the current file structure of the backup file:

`BackupContents.backupxyz
  user.txt
  - folder1
    - audio files
        asdf.caf
        asdf2.caf
  - folder2
    - audio files
        asdf3.caf`

Again, please don't tell me to compress my audio files. That would only be a band-aid to a flawed design.

It seems like I could just move/copy all of the files into a directory using `NSFileManager` and then make that directory a package. Should I go down that path?

Comment: Did you try compressing your audio files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an `NSFileWrapper` tree gets written out to disk, it will attempt to perform a hard-link of the original file to the the new location, but only if you supply a parameter for the `originalContentsURL`.

It sounds like you're constructing the file wrapper programmatically (for the backup scenario), so your files are probably scattered all over the filesystem. This would mean that when you `writeToURL`, you don't *have* an `originalContentsURL`. This means the hard-link logic is going to get skipped, and the file will get loaded so it can get rewritten.

So, if you want the hard-linking behavior, you need to find a way to provide an `originalContentsURL`. This is most easily done by supplying an appropriate URL to the initial `writeToURL` call.

Alternatively, you could try subclassing `NSFileWrapper` for regular files, and giving them an `NSURL` that they internally hang on to. You'd need to override `writeToURL` to pass this new URL up to `super`, but that URL should be enough to trigger the hard-link code. You'd want to then use this subclass of `NSFileWrapper` for the large files you want hard-linked in to place.

Comment: Coincidentally, I was able to fix my problem by simply providing my app's `NSDocumentDirectory` as the `originalContentsURL` on `writeToURL...`. That works in this instance because all of my children file wrappers point to items within that directory. However, this answer is more robust as it handles my situation while also handling the situation where you are pulling files from directories with different ancestry.